# Inequality for inner product involving derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inequality

Let us consider the following: if we assume that $$\langle\partial_b B(b)b,b\rangle \geq C_1 |b|^q$$
holds for any $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $q>1$, $C_1$ some positive constant and where $B:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable (thus $\partial_b B(b)$ is a matrix), can we then conclude that
$$\langle B(b),b\rangle \geq C_2 |b|^q$$
also holds true for any $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $C_2$ is again some positive constant? I am a unsure whether the exponent $q$ on the right in the second inequality still is correct but I can't figure it quite out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anybody got an idea? :-/ Until now I still couldn't figure it out unfortunately...